# Reasons for parents to pierce their son's left ear

Tags: newborn, parents

There is a family that I have known for over 5 years.  We have very different views on parenting, discipline, child rearing, etc.  But one practice of this family (that I thought to be interesting) is that, about 1 month after each of their sons were born, they would pierce their son's left ear.

Normally, I would write this off as something unique to these particular parents, except there is no central motivating reason for the parents (i.e. neither of the parents have any piercings).  Also, I recently encountered another family who seems to have the same practice of piercing their sons' left ears when they are about a month old.

Not having seen this before and knowing that this is not a common practice among parents, I just want to learn more.
Are there reasons (other than preference) for parents to do this?  Or is this just a new fad that is on the rise?

Comment: Without wanting to be nosy, something about the background of these families would perhaps be interesting and helpful - location, social and cultural context, possibly even ethnicity. Even with this information this might be hard to answer, I suspect.

Comment: Have you asked them?

Comment: Sounds like a cultural tradition. They generally have no real reasons for being done, other than "cultural tradition".

Comment: Is this family Indian? Some Indians do this for religious reasons although I think they wait for more than a month.

Comment: This is on the Too Broad side of things, and/or subjective -- we can only guess at the reasons :)

Comment: I disagree with the down votes. The OP is politely asking for clarification on a cultural difference involving 1 month old babies. That seems very appropriate to me.

Comment: I know that the Italian culture likes to pierce baby girls ears very young. I know several toddler girls right now with sparkly earrings. Also, displaying rich cloths and jewelry on infants is a way to show the household wealth in Irish culture. That's easier to do with pierced ears. Or, maybe the dad just has his ear pierced and assumes the son will want it too.

Comment: @Stephie The families are western European in descent. I would guess that they were both lower middle class to middle class families. One family lives in the Boston area; the other lives near Springfield, Ohio.

Comment: Don't have an answer but a couple of thoughts... 1.  Left ear could be significant as that is the "straight ear" stereotypically.  I wonder if some homophobic parents might think this will make their kid straight?  2.  Piercing at that age will be likely be far easier (I think), similar to why tongue clipping for tongue ties is easier at that age (a few weeks old), so perhaps they're thinking he'll want it pierced later and avoid it hurting more/bleeding more?

Comment: @Erica I think it is fine as a question, reading it as "is there a common cultural/religious/ethnic/etc. reason for this".

Comment: hmm - western Europe... could be a Roma/Gypsy thing - I've noticed they're big on ear piercings for babies.  It's likely that their ears were pierced as children and they have removed them and it has regrown.  Without some major input as to the other parents ethnic/cultural background I'm not sure that we can get an answer that wouldn't be entirely guesswork.

Comment: @Joe I think your comment is the best answer we may get.  It's definitely relevant that it is consistently the left ear, but without actually asking the parents we won't reach a definitive answer. +1

Comment: Its just a preference. It used to be that there was a tradition that heterosexuals pierced their left, and gays pierced their right. That tradition varied region to region or community to community. I agree w/ someone's other answer...ask them.

Comment: I've decided vote to close this as too broad, without a significant amount of additional background information on the parents involved we can only guess at the cultural norms that might be in play.  At 1 month old the closest thing to an answer we have is a comment about an 'eastern' religion when the parents in question are of European descent.

Comment: In my country (Belgium), piercing a boy's ear (left or right) so soon is most of the time done by rednecks...

Answer (score 5):

Some cultures practice infant ear piercing. It's common to pierce the ears of infants in the Latino community for example.  But this would be both ears, and it's usually just girls.

Hindus pierce a single ear, and they pierce the ears of both boys and girls.  This can be performed as early as the 10th or 12th day after birth, but is often delayed until the 6th or 7th month. This practice is called *[Karnvedh Sanskar](http://www.sanskritimagazine.com/rituals_and_practices/ear-piercing-in-hinduism/)*. But Hindus would pierce the right ear of boys and the left ear of girls.

So it seems your friends are just following something they've always done.